# Rest API throws JSON parsing error: Exception during JSON parsing at row: 1 column: 1 buffer

Tags: codenameone

I am using Rest API and when I use Rest.put(), it throws an error. It does not even reach the server at all. I don't know where I am going wrong.
Here is my code:

```
Response<String> res = Rest.put(URLLinks.getMainBackend() + "items")
                        .body(reqJson.toString())
                        .jsonContent()
                        .bearer(initForm.data.getString("jwt"))
                        .header("token", initForm.data.getString("token"))
                        .pathParam("id", item.getId())
                        .onErrorCodeJSON((errorData) -> {
                            if (errorData.getResponseCode() == 404) {
                                Dialog dlg = rich.Dialog("Not found!");

                                Button yes = new Button("Close");
                                yes.addActionListener(ev -> {
                                    dlg.dispose();
                                });

                                dlg.add(new SpanLabel("//////!"));
                                dlg.add(FlowLayout.encloseRight(yes));
                                dlg.showPacked(BorderLayout.CENTER, true);
                            }else if (errorData.getResponseCode() == 402){
                               
                            }
                        })
                        .getAsString();
```

It throws an error:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
[Network Thread] 0:0:12,855 - Codename One revisions: 4afb54f6a5cecd2b6fbee170262d5c3c8d9431f9

[Network Thread] 0:0:12,855 - Exception: java.io.IOException - Stream closed
[Network Thread] 0:0:12,858 - Exception during JSON parsing at row: 1 column: 1 buffer: 
[EDT] 0:0:12,874 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
    at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:140)
    at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:338)
    at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:445)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser$ReaderClass.read(JSONParser.java:124)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:188)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parseJSON(JSONParser.java:475)
    at com.codename1.io.rest.RequestBuilder$Connection.readUnzipedResponse(RequestBuilder.java:683)
    at com.codename1.io.gzip.GZConnectionRequest.readResponse(GZConnectionRequest.java:67)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:809)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:282)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:537)
    at com.codename1.io.rest.RequestBuilder.getAsString(RequestBuilder.java:361)
    at com.falcontechnology.items.NewItem.backendItem(NewItem.java:425)
    at com.falcontechnology.items.NewItem.lambda$itemFields$7(NewItem.java:296)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:570)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:604)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:708)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3356)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:4552)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2080)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1052)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:970)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

The null pointer on line NewItem.java:425 points at the line where there is .getAsString().
What could i be doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have updated my project libraries which solved the null pointer exception on .getAsString() but it still leaves another error which is:

```
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
[Network Thread] 0:0:54,316 - Exception: java.io.IOException - Stream closed
[Network Thread] 0:0:54,344 - Exception during JSON parsing at row: 1 column: 1 buffer: 
    at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:140)
    at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:338)
    at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:445)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser$ReaderClass.read(JSONParser.java:191)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:278)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parseJSON(JSONParser.java:568)
    at com.codename1.io.rest.RequestBuilder$Connection.readUnzipedResponse(RequestBuilder.java:785)
    at com.codename1.io.gzip.GZConnectionRequest.readResponse(GZConnectionRequest.java:67)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperationComplete(ConnectionRequest.java:1002)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:340)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that id is null but it's hard to tell since your project libraries seem to be out of date. In Codename One Settings update the project libs depending on the version of Codename One you have.

Comment: Regarding the out dated libraries, I followed the procedures in this link https://www.codenameone.com/blog/netbeans-plugin-update-center.html and while I was updating some other plugins in netbeans, it showed me that it was updating codenameone as well and i didn't mind it. I have just realized that instead downgraded my plugin. Maybe @Shai Almog should look into it.

Comment: That's not the process to update Codename One. That's the process to update the plugin. Codename One is updated via Codename One Settings -> Basic -> Update Project Libs in the old UI and via the menu option on the right in the new UI

Comment: I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently when you use .pathparam(), you also have to add the parameter in the url. Hence I adjusted my code to:

```
Response<String> res = Rest.put(URLLinks.getMainBackend() + "items"+item.getId())
                        .body(reqJson.toString())
                        .jsonContent()
                        .bearer(initForm.data.getString("jwt"))
                        .header("token", initForm.data.getString("token"))
                        .pathParam("id", item.getId())
                        .onErrorCodeJSON((errorData) -> {
                            if (errorData.getResponseCode() == 404) {
                                Dialog dlg = rich.Dialog("Not found!");

                                Button yes = new Button("Close");
                                yes.addActionListener(ev -> {
                                    dlg.dispose();
                                });

                                dlg.add(new SpanLabel("//////!"));
                                dlg.add(FlowLayout.encloseRight(yes));
                                dlg.showPacked(BorderLayout.CENTER, true);
                            }else if (errorData.getResponseCode() == 402){
                               
                            }
                        })
                        .getAsString();
```